# Android AOSP Repo Init fatal: error unknown url type: https

Tags: android, android-source, repository

Can anybody suggest a solution ?

I am running Ubuntu 12.0.4

I have :

```
 Python 2.6 -- 2.7, which you can download from python.org.

    GNU Make 3.81 -- 3.82, which you can download from gnu.org,

    JDK 6 if you wish to build Gingerbread or newer; JDK 5 for Froyo or older. You can download both from java.sun.com.

    Git 1.7 or newer. You can find it at git-scm.com.
```

and have run:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
  libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
  libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
  python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

I have setup my Repo:

Make sure you have a bin/ directory in your home directory and that it is included in your path:

$ mkdir ~/bin
$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH

Download the Repo tool and ensure that it is executable:

$ curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

And then when I run:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

I get the following error

```
fatal: Cannot get https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error unknown url type: https
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what this could be causing this ???

Thanks !!!!

Comment: repo uses urllib. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747037/urllib-py-doesnt-work-with-https ?

Comment: how do i install that ?

Answer (score 3):

Basically I reinstalled Python again and everything worked.
http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution for me as well.

Comment: the point is to reinstall python with openssl support this time.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong url...

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

I was getting same error. Started editing things and changing stuff cuz thought i was wrong. That url must not be functioning but this works for sure:)

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 
fixing the fatal error

```
sudo apt-get install phablet-tools
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Fedora 22, Python 2.7.x) python was compiled without openssl support. I installed the `openssl-devel` package and compiled python from source using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv). Now the repo can handle https.