# Can't access https sites using urllib on python2.7

Tags: python, ssl, https, urllib

```
eduardo@camizao:/$ python2.7 
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> url1 = 'http://www.google.com'
>>> url2 = 'https://www.google.com'
>>> f = urllib.urlopen(url1) 
>>> f = urllib.urlopen(url2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 211, in open
  return getattr(self, name)(url)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 355, in open_http
  'got a bad status line', None)
IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None)
>>>
```

When I try to connect to an https site, using urllib I got error above.
Proxies are correctly setup. Debugging python code, I have noticed in urllib.py that an import on ssl library is not performed. So, https calls are also not performed. Can anyone help me, please? I do have to use urllib, instead of urllib2 or another one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747037/urllib-py-doesnt-work-with-https

Answer (score 0):

It's not something wrong with the way you are writing it at least:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> url1 = 'http://www.google.com'
>>> url2 = 'https://www.google.com'
>>> f = urllib.urlopen(url1)
>>> f = urllib.urlopen(url2)
>>> f.read()[:15]
'<!doctype html>'
>>>
```

So that's what it's not. It must be something with your environment or your config then. You said you are using proxies?

**EDIT:**

I'm able to open it via an open proxy (won't include said proxy because who knows if it is sketchy - substitute with your own proxy:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib2
>>> proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://some-sketchy-open-proxy'})
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
>>> opener.open('https://www.google.com')
<addinfourl at 140512985881056 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7fcbba9b1ed0>>
>>> _.read()[:15]
'<!doctype html>'
>>>
```

Try it that way (note that I used urllib2, not urllib) with your own proxy URL. Hope that helps!

**EDIT 2**:

Using only urllib:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> proxies = {'http': '189.112.3.87:3128'}
>>> url = 'https://www.google.com'
>>> filehandle = urllib.urlopen(url,proxies=proxies)
>>> filehandle.read()[:15]
'<!doctype html>'
>>>
```

Comment: Indeed I'm using a proxy like http://myserver:8080. Curl, Wget and git are working fine, even through a proxy. Is there any other config that I have to perform? Tks

Comment: @camizao Edited the answer with a version that uses a proxy.

Comment: I really appreciate, chucksmash, but I need to use urllib only. Tks